# Updating UISwitch when clicked inside a cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

The problem I had before was if the person pressed `UISwitch` on and clicked into another cell and went back to the homepage, it would show all the buttons off. I am trying to update the switch that if the user presses on, it will stay on even if the user clicks on a different cell. This is what I have so far and I think I am very close. The problem is I don't know what type to make the ??? or what variable I should use. Am I going in the right step or will I face a problem by doing it this way? also do I need to `reloadData` the table?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Create a switch button on each cell

    UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] init];

    //[switchView setOn:NO animated:YES];

    [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(updateSwitch:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

     ??? = (switchView.on) ? YES : NO;

    cell.accessoryView = switchView;

    return cell;
}

- (void)updateSwitch:(id)sender
{
    UISwitch *switcher = (UISwitch *)sender;

    if (switcher.on)
    {
        [switcher setOn: NO animated:YES];
        ??? = NO;
        NSLog(@"OFF");
    }
    else
    {
        [switcher setOn: YES animated: YES];
        ??? = YES;
        NSLog(@"ON");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there more than one switch in the table view? If so, you will need a place to store the state for each of the switches. If this is a small number, you can make properties for each one. Or if it is many, or an undetermined number, you can store the booleans as NSNumbers in an NSArray property.

If you just need to track one switch value you just need a boolean property on your class:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL switchState;
```

And then in your code where you have ??? you can do something like

```
self.switchState = switchView.on;
...
self.switchState = NO;
...
self.switchState = YES;
```

I would recommend not naming it `switchState` but name it what the switch is supposed to represent instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign tag for all switches depend on how many rows are available & apply same logic as above Fabian said. Keep them in some array or dictionary & whenever table loaded you need to check is it ON/OFF state.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, my suggesting is to create both `cellView` and `cellViewController` as a custom cell under `UITableViewCell` class for your `UITableView` and add the switch onto your `cellView`~
Then copy your `updateSwitch` function into `cellViewController` and link it to the switch in your `cellView`
This may help if you want add functional feature for each cell and separate it from the table

TableViewCell.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch * switchView;
- (void)updateSwitch:(id)sender;
```

TableViewCell.m:

```
@synthesize switchView

- (void)setupCell {
    //setting up your cell here, 
    //add your switch on cellView with Interface Builder or initialise it here
    //you may add parameter here for getting data from your table view
    [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(updateSwitch:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }

- (void)updateSwitch:(id)sender
{
    UISwitch *switcher = (UISwitch *)sender;

    if (switcher.on)
    {
        [switcher setOn: NO animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"OFF");
    }
    else
    {
        [switcher setOn: YES animated: YES];
        NSLog(@"ON");
    }
}
```

In your `tableViewControlle`r, you will set up the cell with your `cellView` and `cellViewController`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"table loaded");
    static NSString *tableViewCell = @"tableViewCell";
    TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableViewCell];

    if(cell == nil){
        // load cell view
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil] ;

        for (id oneObject in nib){
            // check if the custom cell class exists            
            if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[TableViewCell class]]){
                cell = [(TableViewCell *)oneObject initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableViewCell];
                }
            }
        }
    [cell setupCell];  //setting up your cell here
    return cell;
}


//finally add click cell event and set sender to the switch in the cell view
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

      TableViewCell * cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      [cell updateSwitch:cell.switchView];

}
```

there is also an either way to do it if you don't wan to create another custom `cellView` and `cellViewController` for your table... it will be an easy and lazy way to make it if your cell for the table is not so complexed

set tag for your switch in the cell when initialised

```
switchView.tag = indexpath.row;
```

and in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` change the switch status for the one with tag